# C++ input of type char, output of type int

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am taking my very first C++ class and I am stuck. I would really appreciate some help from you experienced programmers.

The assignment is creating a blackjack-scoring program. Not a very realistic one, but hey. The user inputs how many cards he wants and then the values of each of those cards. The assignment specifies that the inputs should be in type **char**. So if the user has a 2 card they enter 2, but that 2 is actually **char** and must be converted to **int**. Or they would enter "Q" if they have a queen and my program is supposed to convert that Q to ten points for scoring. I cannot figure out what is the right way to do this. The assignment suggests I will use either a **switch** statement or nested **if-else** statement, but I am afraid I don't understand **switch** very well from the book examples.

So here's a tiny bit of my attempts at switch. *points_for_card* is of type **char** and *number_value* is **int.**

```
switch (points_for_card)
{    
case '2':
   number_value = 2  ;
   break;
case '3':
   number_value = 3  ;
   break;

// ETC
}
```

So what I am going for here is: if the user enters '3' as a char, it becomes int 3. But maybe this is not how switch works at all.

The thing is, my program compiles and works, but returns weird crazy huge numbers. If I move `points_for_card` to `int` instead of `char`, then the arithmetic works perfectly for whatever numbers I enter, because at that point it's just adding them together.

I hope I explained this ok, will clarify as much as possible if necessary.

Comment: This is exactly how `switch` works, and the snippet here is an appropriate use of it.  If your program is "not working" the problem lies elsewhere.  Please show the declaration of `points_for_card` and how you are gathering the input.

Comment: That _is_ how a switch statement is supposed to work, your logic there isn't wrong. How is `points_for_card` defined? is it being input as an int or a char?

Answer (score 3):

it can be something like this code:

```
if (points_for_card >= '1' && points_for_card <= '9'){
    number_value = points_for_card - '0'; // convert to number
}else if (points_for_card == 'Q'){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The ascii (ie char) value of '0' through '9' are ordered.  Which is why the first part works.

Answer (score 0):

A *map* comes to mind. You can store the scores directly, or you can make one map to look up the card type and other maps to associate other information (like score) to each card. Here's the baby example:

```
std::map<char, int> scores;

scores['Q'] = 10; scores['A'] = 13; scores['2'] = 2; // etc.

char c;

std::cout << "Please enter a card: ";
std::cin >> c;

std::cout << "Your card has score " << scores[c] << std::endl;
```

Oftentimes when your heart says "switch", your brain should say "map" :-)

Personnally I'd define an `enum ECardType { Card_2, ..., Card_10, Card_Jack, ... };` and have one map be `std::map<char, ECardType>`, and then other maps from card type to secondary information like scores.

Comment: Using a map gives logarithmic lookup times for a simple input set (known at compile time).  Why not just use the `switch` statement that the OP already has?  The code posted by the OP is not what is causing his failures.

Comment: @Chad: What's the logarithm of 13? What if the OP wants to support multiple languages or card shorthands?

Comment: >1.  Fair enough, but given that this is tagged as homework and the assignment gave a "hint" that they would use a `switch` or nested `if-else-if`, a `std::map` is overkill at best, and a red-flag for the teacher at worst (I bet STL hasn't been covered yet).  Also, this doesn't really have anything to do with the OP's problem as the `switch` statement posted is not problematic.

Comment: Dude .. it's homework, and the OP says *"The assignment suggests I will use either a switch statement or nested if-else statement"*

Answer (score 0):

How are you taking inputs into `points_for_card` ?

Your input should be `cin >> points_for_card`;

Instead of comparing a character to a character, you can also compare it to the ASCII value of a character.
For example,

```
char letter = 'A'
if(letter == 65){
cout << "Match";
}
```

The above code will output "Match!".

Also, your switch statements are perfectly worded. The problem lies elsewhere in your program, so please provide the relevant source.
Another point related to your program but not your problem: How are you dealing with Aces ? You know that they can be counted as either 1 or 11, depending on the player's hand value, right ?

Comment: The constant `'A'` already evaluates to 65.  If your point was that characters are really just numbers, I agree.  If you were suggesting actually using the constant 65, that would be very poor style.